# Expected Saving Value

Tags: probability

I have 4 products and i  have to choose exactly one product out of these four.So probability of choosing a product is `1/4`. The value of money i save is `0 1 0 1` corresponding to each product. What will be the expected value that is saved ?

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

As a hint, try the formula for [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case).

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}0&\mbox{if saved}&0\\1&\mbox{if saved}&1\end{array}\right.$

Then 
$$\begin{eqnarray}&&f_X(0)\\&=&P(X=0)\\&=&P(X=0|\mbox{choose} U_1)P(U_1)+P(X=0|\mbox{choose} U_2)P(U_2)+P(X=0|\mbox{choose} U_3)P(U_3)\\&&+P(X=0|\mbox{choose} U_4)P(U_4)\\
&=&1P(U_1)+0P(U_2)+1P(U_3)+0P(U_4)\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Then $P(X=1)=1-P(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Thus

$E[X]=0P(X=0)+1P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ is the amount of savings, then the distribution of $S$ appears to be
\begin{array}{r|cc}
s&0&1\\\hline
P(S = s)&1/2&1/2
\end{array}
since $0$ and $1$ are equally likely.
Then
$$E[S] = 0\cdot\frac{1}{2}+1\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$$